# Suppress xsi:nil but still show Empty Element when Serializing in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, xml-nil

I have a c# class that has 20+ string properties.  I set about a fourth of those to an actual value.  I would like to serialize the class and get an output of

```
<EmptyAttribute></EmptyAttribute>
```

for a property

```
public string EmptyAttribute {get;set;}
```

I do not want the output to be

```
<EmptyAttribute xsi:nil="true"></EmptyAttribute>
```

I am using the following class

```
public class XmlTextWriterFull : XmlTextWriter
{
    public XmlTextWriterFull(string filename) : base(filename,Encoding.UTF8) { }

    public override void WriteEndElement()
    {
        base.WriteFullEndElement();
        base.WriteRaw(Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

so that I can get the full tags.  I just don't know how to get rid of the xsi:nil.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I need too, but your question is incomplete.  Rather than `<myObject xsi:nil="true" />` you'd like to get `<myObject />` ?  If I find an answer I'll be back!

Comment: I posted my answer below check it out and vote it up if it helps you or if you find a better way post it and let me know.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

I was actually able to figure this out.  I know its a bit of a hack in some ways but this is how I got it to work

```
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(header.GetType());
        XmlTextWriterFull writer = new XmlTextWriterFull(FilePath);
        x.Serialize(writer, header);
        writer.Flush();
        writer.BaseStream.Dispose();
        string xml = File.ReadAllText(FilePath);
        xml = xml.Replace(" xsi:nil=\"true\"", "");
        File.WriteAllText(FilePath, xml);
```

Hope this helps someone else out

Comment: -1... This is awful way to deal with XML please avoid such string manipulations. If you really want to strip attributes - use proper XML API...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov : The whole purpose of the question was to find out the best way to do this - presumably because he didn't know how to use the API to achieve it.  A bit harsh to criticise his not using it.

A better response would be to provide an answer which demonstrates proper use of XML API.

Comment: @ChrisRogers - there is already good answer - so comment is here to steer people away form this on. String manipulation is pretty much never good approach to handle XML.

Answer (score 13):

The way to have the `XmlSerializer` serialize a property without adding the `xsi:nil="true"` attribute is shown below:

```
[XmlRoot("MyClassWithNullableProp", Namespace="urn:myNamespace", IsNullable = false)]
public class MyClassWithNullableProp
{
    public MyClassWithNullableProp( )
    {
        this._namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new XmlQualifiedName[] {
            new XmlQualifiedName(string.Empty, "urn:myNamespace") // Default Namespace
        });
    }

    [XmlElement("Property1", Namespace="urn:myNamespace", IsNullable = false)]
    public string Property1
    {
        get
        {
            // To make sure that no element is generated, even when the value of the
            // property is an empty string, return null.
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(this._property1) ? null : this._property1;
        }
        set { this._property1 = value; }
    }
    private string _property1;

    // To do the same for value types, you need a "helper property, as demonstrated below.
    // First, the regular property.
    [XmlIgnore] // The serializer won't serialize this property properly.
    public int? MyNullableInt
    {
        get { return this._myNullableInt; }
        set { this._myNullableInt = value; }
    }
    private int? _myNullableInt;

    // And now the helper property that the serializer will use to serialize it.
    [XmlElement("MyNullableInt", Namespace="urn:myNamespace", IsNullable = false)]
    public string XmlMyNullableInt
    {
       get 
       {
            return this._myNullableInt.HasValue?
                this._myNullableInt.Value.ToString() : null;
       }
       set { this._myNullableInt = int.Parse(value); } // You should do more error checking...
    }

    // Now, a string property where you want an empty element to be displayed, but no
    // xsi:nil.
    [XmlElement("MyEmptyString", Namespace="urn:myNamespace", IsNullable = false)]
    public string MyEmptyString
    {
        get
        {
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(this._myEmptyString)?
                string.Empty : this._myEmptyString;
        }
        set { this._myEmptyString = value; }
    }
    private string _myEmptyString;

    // Now, a value type property for which you want an empty tag, and not, say, 0, or
    // whatever default value the framework gives the type.
    [XmlIgnore]
    public float? MyEmptyNullableFloat
    {
        get { return this._myEmptyNullableFloat; }
        set { this._myEmptyNullableFloat = value; }
    }
    private float? _myEmptyNullableFloat;

    // The helper property for serialization.
    public string XmlMyEmptyNullableFloat
    {
        get
        {
            return this._myEmptyNullableFloat.HasValue ?
                this._myEmptyNullableFloat.Value.ToString() : string.Empty;
        }
        set
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                this._myEmptyNullableFloat = float.Parse(value);
        }
    }

    [XmlNamespaceDeclarations]
    public XmlSerializerNamespaces Namespaces
    {
        get { return this._namespaces; }
    }
    private XmlSerializerNamespaces _namespaces;
}
```

Now, instantiate this class and serialize it.

```
// I just wanted to show explicitly setting all the properties to null...
MyClassWithNullableProp myClass = new MyClassWithNullableProp( ) {
    Property1 = null,
    MyNullableInt = null,
    MyEmptyString = null,
    MyEmptyNullableFloat = null
};

// Serialize it.
// You'll need to setup some backing store for the text writer below...
// a file, memory stream, something...
XmlTextWriter writer = XmlTextWriter(...) // Instantiate a text writer.

XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClassWithNullableProp),
    new XmlRootAttribute("MyClassWithNullableProp") { 
        Namespace="urn:myNamespace", 
        IsNullable = false
    }
);

xs.Serialize(writer, myClass, myClass.Namespaces);
```

After retrieving the contents of the `XmlTextWriter`, you should have the following output:

```
<MyClassWithNullableProp>
    <MyEmptyString />
     <MyEmptyNullableFloat />
</MyClassWithNullableProp>
```

I hope this clearly demonstrates how the built-in .NET Framework `XmlSerializer` can be used to serialize properties to an empty element, even when the property value is null (or some other value you don't want to serialize). In addition, I have shown how you can make sure that `null` properties are not serialized at all. One thing to note, if you apply an `XmlElementAttribute` and set the `IsNullable` property of that attribute to `true`, then that property will serialize with the `xsi:nil` attribute when the property is `null` (unless overriden somewhere else).

Comment: This is really an excellent way of ensuring empty elements are generated. I already has the serialization code ready. I was only interested in empty element for string property. All I had to do was add a one liner in the property to check String.IsNullOrEmpty and return String.Empty if true. Cheers!!