# how to serialize class objects to xml document

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I hope to find a solution from you. What I need is to serialize ValidatorList class object into an xml document. How to do this?

I tried like this:

```
XmlSerializer _serializer = new XmlSerializer(list);
```

But I don't know how to make output of xml for list that has several classes.

C#

```
_list= new ListVal();
 Type _type = typeof(ras);

 _list.Add(new RequiredField
                    {
                      Property = _type.GetProperty("CustRef")
                    }.Add(new AsciiVal()));
_list.Add(new RequiredField
                  {
                    Property = _type.GetProperty("ctr")
                  }.Add(new StringLengthVal
                          {
                            min= 3,
                            max= 3
                          }));

[Serializable]
 public class Field
 {
public Field Next
{
  get;
  set;
}

public Field TypeName
{
  get;
  set;
}

    public Field PropertyName
  {
  get;
  set;
}
}

public class RequiredField : Field
{
//TODO
 }

public class AsciiVal: Field
 {
//TODO
  }

public class StringLengthVal: Field
 {
//TODO
}

 public class ListVal: List<Field>
 {
//TODO
  }
```

Comment: FYI the process of turning an object into a stream of data (such as Xml) is *serialization*. *deserialization* is going the other way. Ive updated your question with the right phrases to make it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have something close, but not exactly the Xml you want. In actual fact I think you'll see that the Xml produced below makes a bit more sense than what you have.

To get you started, you control the serialization and deserialization using attributes in the [`System.Xml.Serialization` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.Serialization.aspx). A few useful ones to read up on are

- [`XmlRootAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute.aspx)
- [`XmlElementAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx)
- [`XmlAttributeAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute.aspx)
- [`XmlIncludeAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute.aspx)

So I mocked up some code which closely matches your own. Notice the addition of some attributes to instruct the serializer how I want the Xml to be laid out.

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(AsciiValidator))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(RequiredValidator))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(StringLengthValidator))]
public class FieldValidator
{
    [XmlElement("Next")]
    public FieldValidator Next
    {
    get;
    set;
    }

    [XmlElement("PropertyName")]
    public string PropertyName
    {
    get;
    set;
    }
}

public class AsciiValidator: FieldValidator
{
}

public class RequiredValidator: FieldValidator
{
}

public class StringLengthValidator: FieldValidator
{
    [XmlElement]
    public int MinLength{get;set;}
    [XmlElement]
    public int MaxLength{get;set;}
}

[XmlRoot("ValidatorList")]
public class ValidatorList : List<FieldValidator>
{    
}
```

Point of interest; Every class inheriting `FieldValidator` must be added to the list of known types using `XmlIncludeAttribute` so the serializer knows what to do with them)

Then I created an example object map:

```
var test = new ValidatorList();
test.Add(
            new RequiredValidator()
                {
                    PropertyName="CustRef",
                    Next = new AsciiValidator()
                });            
test.Add(
            new RequiredValidator()
                {
                    PropertyName="CurrencyIndicator",
                        Next = new StringLengthValidator(){
                            MinLength=3,
                            MaxLength = 10
                        }
                });
```

Finally I told the serializer to serialize it (and output the result to the console)

```
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ValidatorList));
ser.Serialize(Console.Out,test);
```

This was the result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ValidatorList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <FieldValidator xsi:type="RequiredValidator">
    <Next xsi:type="AsciiValidator" />
    <PropertyName>CustRef</PropertyName>
  </FieldValidator>
  <FieldValidator xsi:type="RequiredValidator">
    <Next xsi:type="StringLengthValidator">
      <MinLength>3</MinLength>
      <MaxLength>10</MaxLength>
    </Next>
    <PropertyName>CurrencyIndicator</PropertyName>
  </FieldValidator>
</ValidatorList>
```

Not a million miles away from what you wanted. There is the need to output certain things in a certain way (eg `xsi:type` tells the serializer how to deserialize back to the object map). I hope this gives you a good start.

Here is a live, working example: http://rextester.com/OXPOB95358

Deserialization can be done by calling the [`Deserialize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize.aspx) method on the XmlSerializer.

For example, if your xml is in a string:

```
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ValidatorList));
var test = "<..../>" // Your Xml
var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(test));
var validatorList = (ValidatorList)ser.Deserialize(xmlReader);
```

There are many overrides of Deserialize which take differing inputs depending if the data is in a Stream an existing reader, or saved to a file.

Comment: By calling one of the `Deserialize` methods on [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx)

Comment: i have tried it - it is not working. i would like to see yours what is like so that i can understand. thanks so much for ur time :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to decorate the class that contains the _validators field with the KonwnType attribute

```
[Serializable]
[KwownType(typeof(RequiredFieldValidator)]
[KwownType(typeof(AsciValidator)]
public class MySerialisableClass
```

Answer (score 0):

I have several SO answers that detail how to serialize objects using XML. I'll provide links below.

However, since you're looking for a rather simple serialization of your object, you may want to read up on the `DataContractSerializer`. It's much less complicated than the old .NET 1.x XML Serialization.

Here's the list of SO answers:

- [Omitting all xsi and xsd namespaces when serializing an object in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625927/omitting-all-xsi-and-xsd-namespaces-when-serializing-an-object-in-net/11129732#11129732)
- [XmlSerializer: remove unnecessary xsi and xsd namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760262/xmlserializer-remove-unnecessary-xsi-and-xsd-namespaces/11138262#11138262)
- [Suppress xsi:nil but still show Empty Element when Serializing in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710107/suppress-xsinil-but-still-show-empty-element-when-serializing-in-net/11200266#11200266)
- [Using XmlAttributeOverrides on Nested Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525904/using-xmlattributeoverrides-on-nested-properties/16527198#16527198)

Even though many of these have to do with XML serialization and namespaces, they contain complete examples of serializing an object to XML using .NET 1.x XML Serialization.